# add background "bars" to extend header image with color. or put image over div bars

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

I basically made a header image for my site and the sides of it have black on it. I want to extend the header so it goes for the width of the  user's web browser with black "bars" as if the header extends for their whole browser.

I've tried a few things, but I cant figure this out.

Here's an example of what I have now:

```
#header {
    background: url('img/header.png') no-repeat top center;
    height: 131px;
    }

#headerbg {
    height: 131px;
    width:4000px;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

And in the html I just have both in divs and within each other in the html.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. Please try to set up a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NPLEm/) that shows you how to layer the two div's and use `background-size` property to expand the image so it fits just the same as the background color's width. UPDATE: New jsFiddle above is replaced to include better method for that type of look.

**Edit:** Here is a different [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9W3bx/) that has places the image inside and centers it, allowing any excess background color from the parent container to show through.

**Edit 2:** Using the Edit fiddle above, you can apply CSS3/IE gradient effect as shown in this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9W3bx/1/)

**Status:** The solution was to use `center center` for `background-position` combined with setting both `width and height` to `100%` for the image used.

Comment: Thanks for the sketch. Also, there are many [Mockup Tools](http://designmodo.com/free-wireframe-mockup/) online too!

Comment: awesome, i had no idea there was were so many tools online. i'm looking at your solution right now btw. you made it look so simple.. i have no idea what im doing with my code right now lol. i knew this was simple.. not sure what the problem is right now, need to try what you did

Comment: thank you so much attronics. i finally got it to work. you know what my problem was initially? i kept not saving my style sheet and only saving my html file in dreamweaver? i was like.. how is his solution not working for me right now? lol. live and learn, eh? thanks again. :)

Comment: i require 15 reputation. -_- ill come back and upvote you when i gain the rep lol