# fix-width for header footer when resizing window

Tags: html, css, header, footer

I have html and body set to width: 100% position: absolute
and header, footer width: 100%.

So when I resize the window, the header footer also resize. How can I make them to have a fixed width which is the window's maximum width??? Especially after resizing, header footer dont stretch all the way to the right

Thank you so much for ur help

```
<pre>
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }

    body {   
        position: absolute;  
        font-family: Helvetica, Garamond, serif;  
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
    }

    #footer {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: -150px;
    }

    #header, #footer {
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #header {
        height: 100px;
    }

</pre>
```

Comment: why do you need `position: absolute` on `<body>`? Remove it and you should be fine

Comment: @ZoltanToth: thanks but it doesn't work. the header still doesn't stretch all the way to the right as I resize the window.

Comment: Seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/wdzhK/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min-width` property to apply a minimum width that is required by the div...

Answer (score 0):

I have **3 jsFiddles** you can look at including `Edit` and `Edit2` [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10973303/1195891).

Is that what you want?